# Find the marginal pdf of $X$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The joint pdf of $X$ and $Y$ is given by
$$ f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \frac{1}{8} (y^2 - x^2) e^{-y} I_{(0, \infty)}(y) I_{(-y,y)}(x)$$

Find the marginal pdf of $X$

**My attempt:**

$f_X(x) = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{8} (y^2 - x^2) e^{-y} I_{(-y,y)}(x)dy = \\=
\int_{-x}^{\infty} \frac{1}{8} (y^2 - x^2) e^{-y} I_{(-\infty,0)}(x)dy + \int_{x}^{\infty} \frac{1}{8} (y^2 - x^2) e^{-y} I_{(0, \infty)}(x)dy = \\= 
\frac{1}{4} e^x(x^2 - x + 1)  I_{(-\infty,0)}(x)+ \frac{1}{4} e^{-x}(x^2 +x + 1) I_{(0, \infty)}(x)$

but this is not a pdf.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: 
$$
I_{(0, \infty)}(y) I_{(-y,y)}(x)=I_{(|x|, \infty)}(y).
$$
Consequence of the hint: the general identity
$$
f_X(x)=\int_\mathbb R f_{X,Y}(x,y)\mathrm dy$$
reads in the present case
$$
f_X(x)=\int_{|x|}^{+\infty}\frac18(y^2-x^2)\mathrm e^{-y}\mathrm dy,
$$
that is,
$$
f_X(x)=\left.-\frac18(y^2+2y+2-x^2)\mathrm e^{-y}\right|_{|x|}^\infty=\frac14\mathrm e^{-|x|}(1+|x|).
$$

Comment: but what I did wrong?

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+1%2F8+exp%28-%7Cx%7C%29+%282x%5E2+%2B+2%7Cx%7C+%2B+2%29+for+x+%3D+-%5Cinfty+to+%5Cinfty

Comment: To begin with, how is $I_{(-y,y)}(x)$ supposed to yield an integral from $-x$ to $+\infty$ plus an integral from $x$ to $+\infty$? I have trouble even suggesting a mechanism for this error...

Comment: I just splitted the region in 2 parts. Can you solve it, then? Using modulus, I got 2 as answer too

Comment: "I just splitted the region in 2 parts." No you did not, actually you transcribed incorrectly the domain. "Can you solve it, then?" I just did, see answer above.